# Schnorr signature variant with sum c and k instead of multiplication

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

I am reading about Schnorr signature and I though what if we calculate response as $r = \alpha + c + k$ instead of $r = \alpha + c*k$? Will it make scheme more insecure? Are there any name for this scheme?

So, signing: $k = privatekey, \alpha = random, c = HASH(message, \alpha*G, k*G), r = \alpha + c + k, signature = (\alpha*G, r)$

Comment: Remember the definition of security for a signature scheme is existential unforgeability under chosen message attack. Can you devise an existential forgery?

Comment: It might be something obvious but I still did not get it. How making $r = \alpha + c*k$ makes it more secure than $r = \alpha + c + k$? You still need to know private key $k$ to calculate $r$

Comment: In a chosen message attack, the adversary is allowed to query for signatures of arbitrary messages. For an existential forgery, the adversary must forge the signature of a message whose signature was **not** queried for. Your scheme is insecure using these definitions. This isn't exactly obvious, but it's not hard to do with some effort, and it's also standard modern cryptographic theory nowadays. It would be well worth your time to learn modern theory if you intend to do anything even remotely serious with cryptography. I recommend https://joyofcryptography.com/ or http://toc.cryptobook.us/

Comment: [Cryptography StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) is probably a better place for questions of this nature.